# Mesos Marathon(ctl) Debugging - "Abnormal executor termination: unknown container"

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon

I'm still new to Mesos, but am trying to figure out the best way to debug a Mesos application I'm attempting to develop. I'm getting the error message "Abnormal executor termination: unknown container" through the web application, and am unsure how to get more descriptive error messages to figure out what's going on. The error message would seem to indicate it can't find the Docker image, but I know for a fact it's referencing the correct image that is installed and running.

```
{
  "id": "pgprimary",
  "cmd": null,
  "cpus": 1,
  "mem": 128,
  "disk": 0,
  "instances": 1,
  "container": {
    "docker": {
      "image": "example/postgres:centos7-10.0-1.6.0",
      "network": "BRIDGE",
      "parameters": [{
    "key": "hostname",
    "value": "pgprimary"
    }],
      "portMappings": [
      ]
    },
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "volumes": [
      {
        "hostPath": "/mnt/nfsfileshare/pgdata",
        "containerPath": "/pgdata",
        "mode": "RW"
      }
    ]
  },
  "env": {
    "PG_MODE": "primary",
    "PG_USER": "testuser",
    "PG_PASSWORD": "testuser",
    "PG_DATABASE": "userdb",
    "PG_ROOT_PASSWORD": "password",
    "PG_PRIMARY_USER": "primaryuser",
    "PG_PRIMARY_PASSWORD": "password",
    "PG_PRIMARY_PORT": "5432"
  },
  "labels": {},
  "healthChecks": [
    {
      "protocol": "COMMAND",
      "command": {
        "value": "/usr/pgsql-10/bin/pg_isready --host=pgprimary.marathon.mesos"
      },
      "gracePeriodSeconds": 300,
      "intervalSeconds": 60,
      "timeoutSeconds": 20,
      "maxConsecutiveFailures": 3,
      "ignoreHttp1xx": false
    }
  ]
}
```

The command I'm using to deploy the Marathon app:

```
marathonctl -h http://10.0.2.15:8080 app create postgres.json
```

Comment: I did some digging and it looks like this might be related to your user permissions... See [this post](https://github.com/docker/swarm/issues/1177). Hope it helps!

Comment: Can you share Mesos agent configuration? Especially what containerizer is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Not image, but docker is what marathon cannot find.
Specify the use of the Docker containerizer:

```
echo 'docker,mesos' > /etc/mesos-slave/containerizers
```

Provisioning Containers with the Docker Containerizer
https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html